# Select rows from dataframe with a certain character after a '-'

Tags: pandas, dataframe, querying

I have the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
test = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'A1-C-D-1 A22-C-D-22 A4-S-E-3'.split(),
             'B': [1, 2, 3]})
```

I want to select the rows that have a certain character (for example 'E') after the second '-'

Any ideas would be very welcome!

Comment: Thanks for accepting! You can also upvote solutions if you found them useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**
Filter with `str.split` + `str.startswith`:

```
test[test.A.str.split('-').str[2].str.startswith('E')]

          A  B
2  A4-S-E-3  3
```

---

**Option 2**
You can get inventive and use `str.extract` + `pd.Series.notna/notnull` here:

```
test[test.A.str.extract('.*?-.*?-(E).*', expand=False).notna()]

          A  B
2  A4-S-E-3  3
```